# "Might as well be" vs "might as well been."

Tags: tense, simile

Say, you're writing in the past tense. And you want to make a simile-like comparison.

Should you use "might as well be" or "might as well been"? And why?

Example:

> She squinted at the typed words, bewildered. She might **as well
>   be/might as well been** reading an ineligible, ancient scripture.

I have the same kind of doubt with "could be" vs "could have been."

> She gawked at him until her jaw hurt. She **could be/could've been**
>   looking at a spirit.

I think my confusion lies in the fact that *might* and *could* can be used in the past tense.

Comment: *Might as well **have** been.* With that change, both are fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the whole paragraph is in past tense, you should us have been. Note that this sentence needs a helping verb (have).

Comment: I see. So *might as well have been* and *could have been*?

Comment: Yes, you got it.